# Comparing two lists of symbols in lisp

Tags: comparison, lisp, common-lisp

Let's say I have two lisp lists that are the same but in different sequence: `'(A B C)` and '`(C B A)`.
How can I check if they are the same (in the sense that the elements are the same)?

```
CL-USER> (equal '(a b c) '(c b a))
NIL
```

Comment: Seems like a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4110742/16240).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
  (not (set-exclusive-or '(a b c) '(c b a)))
```

which returns `T` if the two sets are equal, NIL otherwise.

[Edit] If they are not truly sets then you could use this:

```
  (not (set-exclusive-or 
         (remove-duplicates '(a b c))
         (remove-duplicates '(c b a))))
```

Comment: that works for 'sets', but not for lists in general. `(not (set-exclusive-or '(a b c) '(c b a a)))`  `->`  `t`
Maybe that's what is needed, maybe not.

Answer (score 3):

If the lists are not sets and repeated items are important, one could use a function like this:

```
(defun same-elements-p (a b)
  (loop (when (and (null a) (null b)) 
          (return t))
        (when (or (null a) (null b))
          (return nil))
        (setf b (remove (pop a) b :count 1))))
```

If both lists are empty, they are the same. We remove all items of one list from the other and see what happens. Note the `:count 1` argument to `REMOVE`. It makes sure than only one item is removed.

Answer (score 1):

We can define the functions `perm-equal` and `perm-equalp` which are similar to EQUAL and EQUALP except that if the arguments are lists, then their permutation doesn't matter. The list `(1 1 2 3)` is `perm-equal` to `(2 1 3 1)`, but not to `(2 3 1)`.

The implementation works by normalizing values into a canonical permutation by sorting. This brings up the ugly spectre of requiring an inequality comparison. However, we can hide that by providing a predefined one which works for numbers, symbols and strings. (Why doesn't the `sort` function do something like this, the way `eql` is defaulted as the `:key` parameter?)

```
(defun less (a b)
  (if (realp a)
    (< a b)
    (string< a b)))

(defun lessp (a b)
  (if (realp a)
    (< a b)
    (string-lessp a b)))

(defun perm-equal (a b &optional (pred #'less))
  (if (or (atom a) (atom b))
    (equal a b)
    (let ((as (sort (copy-list a) pred))
          (bs (sort (copy-list b) pred)))
      (equal as bs))))

(defun perm-equalp (a b &optional (pred #'lessp))
  (if (or (atom a) (atom b))
    (equalp a b)
    (let ((as (sort (copy-list a) pred))
          (bs (sort (copy-list b) pred)))
      (equalp as bs))))
```

Notes:

- Doesn't handle improper lists: it just tries to sort them and it's game over.
- Even though `equalp` compares vectors, `perm-equalp` doesn't extend its permutation-squashing logic over vectors.
- `realp` is used to test for numbers because complex numbers satisfy `numberp`, yet cannot be compared with `<`.

Answer (score 1):

The trivial answer for non-sets is to sort both lists. CL's default sort is destructive, so you'll need copies if you want to keep them afterwards.

```
(defun sorted (a-list predicate)
  (sort (copy-list a-list) predicate))

(defun same-list-p (list-a list-b predicate)
  (equalp (sorted list-a predicate) (sorted list-b predicate)))
```

It doesn't have the best performance, but is simple and functional.

Comment: @wvxvw - See "...doesn't have the best performance, but is simple and functional". The point of this answer was to sit counter to yours as a two-liner with clarity as the primary goal.

Comment: @wvxvw - I don't consider it a problem that datatypes we're unconcerned with won't be handled by this approach (especially since the alternative, as demonstrated by your own answer, is to greatly complicate the solution). The question asks specifically about symbols, whose names can be sorted.

Comment: @wvxvw - "Comparing two lists of symbols in lisp" seems pretty specific to me.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like an O(n) variant:

```
(defun equal-elementwise (a b &key (test #'eq))
  (loop with hash = (make-hash-table :test test)
     for i on a for j on b do
       (let ((i (car i)) (j (car j)))
         (unless (funcall test i j)
           (setf (gethash i hash) (1+ (gethash i hash 0))
                 (gethash j hash) (1- (gethash j hash 0)))))
     finally (return
               (unless (or (cdr i) (cdr j))
                 (loop for value being the hash-value of hash do
                      (unless (zerop value) (return))
                    finally (return t))))))
```

However, this won't be efficient on short lists.